# Excel sheet cells to different sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I need to find a script that allows me to use information from the index sheet in a workbook.

- I need it to take the data from the range A3:G304.
- The data will be spread into their respective sheets.
- The sheets are named for the value in the column A and need to be placed in cells as follows A to A1; B to A2; C to to A3; D to B3; E to C3; F to E2; G to G2.
- Each row corresponds to a different sheet.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Have you tried `cell` and `indirect`?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code you need:

```
Dim targetSheet As Worksheet
Dim rowIndex, columnCount As Integer

Set targetSheet = ActiveSheet
columnCount = UBound(initialRange, 2)


For rowIndex = 3 To 304
    Set targetSheet = Sheets.Add(After:=targetSheet)
    ' The (Row #) is added to sheet name to prevent Workbook from having duplicated name sheets
    ' Remove if not applicable
    targetSheet.Name = Cells(rowIndex, "A").Value & " (Row " & rowIndex & ")"

    Cells(rowIndex, "A").Resize(1, 7).Copy
    targetSheet.Cells(columnCount, "A").End(xlUp).PasteSpecial Transpose:=True
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
Next rowIndex
```

The only problem is that Excel will probably run out of ressources with over 300 WorkSheets.